# How do I get current playing time and total play time in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, avplayer

Is it possible get playing time and total play time in AVPlayer? If yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You can access currently played item by using `currentItem` property:

```
AVPlayerItem *currentItem = yourAVPlayer.currentItem;
```

Then you can easily get the requested time values

```
CMTime duration = currentItem.duration; //total time
CMTime currentTime = currentItem.currentTime; //playing time
```

**Swift 5**:

```
if let currentItem = player.currentItem {
    let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.duration)
    let currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.currentTime())

    print("Duration: \(duration) s")
    print("Current time: \(currentTime) s")
}
```

Comment: there is also convenient method CMTimeGetSeconds to get NSTimeInterval:
    NSTimeInterval duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.duration);
    NSTimeInterval currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.currentTime);

Comment: i had to set call it in main queue for it to return the right value (or whatever queue your avplayer is running in).

Comment: how to give this propety to LABEL?

Comment: i am playing song from url . but at CMTime duration and CMTime currentTime i am getting 0 . what is the problem here for 0 value ? does anyone know the solution ?

Comment: NSTimeInterval duration3 = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.duration);
    NSTimeInterval currentTime3 = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.currentTime);
    
    NSLog(@"%f and %f",duration3,currentTime3);

   
    self.playbackSlider.value = currentTime3/duration3;

Comment: How come the `currentTime().seconds` is sometimes greater than the `duration`? I can't find the answer and this happens every time when the asset plays to the end (I fetch the `currentTime` every half a second): `currentTime: 19.50039306 of 20.0 -> currentTime: 20.0002372 of 20.0 ->
currentTime: 20.000558334 of 20.0`

Answer (score 25):

```
_audioPlayer = [self playerWithAudio:_audio];
_observer =
[_audioPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(1, 2)
                                           queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()
                                      usingBlock:^(CMTime time)
                                      {
                                          _progress = CMTimeGetSeconds(time);
                                      }];
```

Answer (score 23):

**Swift 3**

```
let currentTime:Double = player.currentItem.currentTime().seconds
```

You can get the seconds of your current time by accessing the `seconds` property of the `currentTime()`. This will return a `Double` that represents the seconds in time. Then you can use this value to construct a readable time to present to your user.

First, include a method to return the time variables for `H:mm:ss` that you will display to the user:

```
func getHoursMinutesSecondsFrom(seconds: Double) -> (hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Int) {
    let secs = Int(seconds)
    let hours = secs / 3600
    let minutes = (secs % 3600) / 60
    let seconds = (secs % 3600) % 60
    return (hours, minutes, seconds)
}
```

Next, a method that will convert the values you retrieved above into a readable string:

```
func formatTimeFor(seconds: Double) -> String {
    let result = getHoursMinutesSecondsFrom(seconds: seconds)
    let hoursString = "\(result.hours)"
    var minutesString = "\(result.minutes)"
    if minutesString.characters.count == 1 {
        minutesString = "0\(result.minutes)"
    }
    var secondsString = "\(result.seconds)"
    if secondsString.characters.count == 1 {
        secondsString = "0\(result.seconds)"
    }
    var time = "\(hoursString):"
    if result.hours >= 1 {
        time.append("\(minutesString):\(secondsString)")
    }
    else {
        time = "\(minutesString):\(secondsString)"
    }
    return time
}
```

Now, update the UI with the previous calculations:

```
func updateTime() {
    // Access current item
    if let currentItem = player.currentItem {
        // Get the current time in seconds
        let playhead = currentItem.currentTime().seconds
        let duration = currentItem.duration.seconds
        // Format seconds for human readable string
        playheadLabel.text = formatTimeFor(seconds: playhead)
        durationLabel.text = formatTimeFor(seconds: duration)
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a property on player that returns milliseconds?

Answer (score 17):

Swift 4

```
    self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoUrl!)
    self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem)

    self.player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { (time) in
        if self.player!.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
            let currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player!.currentTime())

            let secs = Int(currentTime)
            self.timeLabel.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", secs/60, secs%60) as String//"\(secs/60):\(secs%60)"

    })
}
```

Answer (score 16):

With Swift 4.2, use this;

```
let currentPlayer = AVPlayer()
if let currentItem = currentPlayer.currentItem {
    let duration = currentItem.asset.duration
}
let currentTime = currentPlayer.currentTime()
```

Comment: I tried to use AVPlayer.currentTime() , but no luck, getting bad access error

Comment: currentPlayer.currentItem.currentTime() - you. will. get correct time.

Comment: this answer is 100% correct but if you initialize the player without an avasset you have to use: **player?.currentItem?.duration*. It's better to use an avasset

Comment: Could someone please provide a full example of how to use this in SwiftUI please?

Comment: @Aiyush you need to use VideoPlayer for SwiftUI.

Comment: @KemalCanKaynak I'm struggling with this. How can I get the current time using VideoPlayer ie. if the current time in video is 10 seconds then print("Hello") or show some Text etc... I would really appreciate this :)

Answer (score 7):

Swift 5:
Timer.scheduledTimer seems better than addPeriodicTimeObserver if you want to have a smooth progress bar

```
var currenTime = 0.0
var currenTimeString = "00:00"

func showAudioTime()
{
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1/60, repeats: true) { timer in
        guard let player = self.player else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            if player.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
                let timeElapsed = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
                let secs = Int(timeElapsed)
                self.currenTime = timeElapsed
                self.currenTimeString = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", secs/60, secs%60) as String
                
                self.currentPlaybackTimeLabel.text = self.currenTimeString
                
                print("AudioPlayer TIME UPDATE: \(self.currenTime)    \(self.currenTimeString)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: really, you have to animate smooth progress bars from point to point - it's not so easy. you'd definitely never use a trimer (for any reason) with 1/60 - just use CADisplayLink

Comment: The other answers using `addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval:` are quite powerful. For example, the interval being a CMTime, create an interval of `CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 100)`. That means you'll receive 100 time observations every 1 seconds. So here, 0.01s 0.02s 0.03s etc.

Answer (score 5):

```
     AVPlayerItem *currentItem = player.currentItem;
     NSTimeInterval currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.currentTime);
     NSLog(@" Capturing Time :%f ",currentTime);
```

Comment: i am playing song from url . but at CMTime duration and CMTime currentTime i am getting 0 . what is the problem here for 0 value ? does anyone know the solution ?

Answer (score 5):

Swift:

```
let currentItem = yourAVPlayer.currentItem

let duration = currentItem.asset.duration
var currentTime = currentItem.asset.currentTime
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2:

```
let currentItem = yourAVPlayer.currentItem
let duration = currentItem.asset.duration
let currentTime = currentItem.currentTime()
```

Answer (score 1):

in swift 5+

You can query the player directly to find the current time of the actively playing AVPlayerItem.
The time is stored in a CMTime Struct for ease of conversion to various scales such as 10th of sec, 100th of a sec etc
In most cases we need to represent times in seconds so the following will show you what you want

```
let currentTimeInSecs = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
```

Comment: added :) hope this helps

Comment: Would you mind adding an example of how to implement this fully in SwiftUI? It would be really appreciated! :)

Comment: That's beyond the scope of the above question, but here is a descent tutorial you might find helpful https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course_video?id=282